# On what page of the Quran does it say that we are not allowed to kill other Non-Muslims?

Tags: quran, halal-haram

^^^^^^ (I know that)

I know that killing other Muslim is extremely forbidden, but what about Non-Muslim?

Are we forbidden to hurt/kill them too?

Also if someone knows this, on what page can we find this about killing is haram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing somebody without any reason is sin as killing any Muslim.

> And We have not sent you, [O Muhammad], except as a mercy to the worlds.
>   *21 -Surat Al-'Anbyā' - 107* [source](http://quran.com/21/107)

If the one who lead is merciful then why do we oppose out leader.

Answer (score 1):

Human life is regarded as sacred and inviolable, except with valid reason (such as war or a legal sentence after a trial) and normally verses with regard to this does not qualify/distinguish life as life of Muslims or non Muslims.

> Say: Come I will recite what your Lord has forbidden to you--
>   (remember) that you do not associate anything with Him and show
>   kindness to your parents, and do not slay your children for (fear of)
>   poverty-- We provide for you and for them-- and do not draw nigh to
>   indecencies, those of them which are apparent and those which are
>   concealed, **and do not kill the soul which Allah has forbidden except
>   for the requirements of justice**; this He has enjoined you with that
>   you may understand. ([6:151](http://quran.com/6/151))
>
> For this reason did We prescribe to the children of Israel that
>   **whoever slays a soul, unless it be for manslaughter or for mischief in
>   the land, it is as though he slew all men; and whoever keeps it alive,
>   it is as though he kept alive all men**; ... 
>   ([5:32](http://quran.com/5/32))